Prove or disprove: there exists three vertexes a,b,c in a connected but incomplete graph satisfying a and b have a common neighbor c

In a connected graph which is not complete, can we find three vertices denoted by a,b,c such that a is adjacent to b, b is adjacent to c, but a and c are not neighbors?

That's a graph theory problem in my CS textbook called Graph Theory & Algorithm. After learning the definition of the cut vertex and the bridge and the Tarjan algorithm for finding the cut vertex, my teacher raised this problem. It is obvious to some extent but the formalized verification is necessary.
I tried to assume to the converse that we can't find such three vertices. And then there are three situations to consider: there are no or one or three pairs of neighbors among the arbitrary three vertexes of this graph. That confused me a lot.

Seems true, from a quick visual proof. Start with three connected vertices A-B-C. If A and C are not adjacent, then you need to connect them. But now the graph is complete. So we connect another vertex D-A. But now D-A-B and D-A-C. So we connect B-D and C-D. But now it's a complete graph. So we connect another vertex E-A... Ad infinitum.

Since the graph is incomplete, there are two vertices, say A and Z, with no edge AZ in the graph. Since the graph is connected, there is some path A B C … X Y Z. There is at least one vertex on this path with an edge to Z, since Y is one. Let Q be the first such vertex. Let P be the preceding vertex on the path. Then PZ is not in the graph but PQ and QZ are.

Thank you for your reply! I think that only when the path is the shortest one, PZ is definitely not in the graph. Otherwise, PZ is possibly in the graph. Do you agree with me?

@advance: No. Q is defined to be the first vertex in the path such that QZ is in the graph. Since P precedes Q, PZ is not in the graph.

On this path, PZ is not in the graph. But there may be some other path connecting P and Z? I kind of,don't understand what the preceding mean.

@advance: We do not care if P and Z are connected. (We know they are, since the graph is complete.) The criterion is to find A, B, and C with AB and BC in the graph and AC not. P, Q, and Z satisfy this since PQ and QZ are in the graph and PZ is not.

Thank you! "Q is the first vertex on this path such that QZ is in the graph" means that the vertexes preceding Q are not adjacent to Z? How do we guarantee that?

@advance: As stated, the fact the graph is connected means there is a path from A to Z. We know AZ is not in the graph. Examine the second vertex on the path to see if it has an edge to Z. If not, examine the third. Then the fourth. And so on until a vertex with an edge to Z is found. There must be one, since the second-to-last vertex has an edge to Z, and there must be a first one.

OK! Thank you so much for your patience. I understand! The idea is fantastic!

I like this answer, but note that the problem can be restated:  "Can we find a pair of vertices such that the distance between them is 2".

Notation:

Let A-B denote vertices A and B such that A is adjacent to B.
Let A-B-C denote vertices A, B, C such that A is adjacent to B, B is adjacent to C, but A and C are not adjacent.

Notice that in any induced subgraph S of a graph G, if there exists A-B-C in S, then there exists that same A-B-C in G.

Statement. In a connected graph G which is not complete, there exists A-B-C in G.

Assume the statement is false.
Let G be a connected non-complete graph.
Base case: Let us consider any induced subgraph S_3 of G containing exactly three vertices A, B, C such that A-B and B-C. (Clearly, there exists such a subgraph, for if not, G cannot be connected.) Now, if A-B-C, the statement would be true, so this means that A-C. Thus, S_3 is complete.
Inductive step: Let S_(k-1) = {A, B, ..., J} be a complete induced subgraph of G containing exactly (k-1) vertices. Since G is connected, there must be a connected induced subgraph S_k = {A, B, ..., J, K} of exactly k vertices which has the aforementioned S_(k-1) as a subgraph. WLOG, say K-A to ensure connectedness. Furthermore, for any vertex X ∈ {B, ..., J}, we have A-X. Now, if K-A-X, the statement would be true, so this means that K-X. Thus, S_k is complete.
Clearly, by induction, there is a sequence S_3, S_4, S_5, ..., G of complete induced subgraphs of G. However, we assumed that G must not be complete.
We have reached a contradiction, and so the statement must be true.

Re “Thus, any induced subgraph S of G containing exactly three vertices must necessarily be connected for the statement to be false”: You did not show this. You showed that any induced subgraph S of G containing three vertices such that A-B and B-C must be complete (not connected). This does not speak to induced subgraphs of G containing exactly three vertices that have zero or one edges.

@Eric Postpischil Yeah, that's true. We need to discuss three vertices that have zero or one edges.

@EricPostpischil You're right, what I said didn't convincingly show that G would have to be complete. I think I managed to repair the proof, though it's not phrased in a particularly elegant way.

Your base case starts “Let us consider any induced subgraph S_3 of a connected graph G containing exactly three vertices A, B, C such that A-B and B-C” but draws a conclusion about “any connected induced subgraph S_3 of connected G containing exactly three vertices.” That conclusion is not demonstrated; the base case only demonstrates a property of a subgraph of three vertices with A-B and B-C, not a property of all subgraphs with three vertices.

Regarding the induction, observe that it can only start with k=4. For k=3, there is no strict subgraph with three vertices, so the base case cannot apply. This means you need to prove k=3 separately. (That is easily done since incompleteness and connectedness force a graph with AB, BC, and not AC. Graphs of 2, 1, and 0 vertices should also be covered, although they are trivial. I had this in mind when writing my proof and let it be covered by the fact that the graph is incomplete implies there are two vertices, and then the fact it is complete implies there is a third.)

Are you aware of the “proof” that all horses are white? Suppose in each set of n horses, all of the horses are the same color. This is trivially true for n=1. Suppose it is true for n=k for some k. Then consider any set of k+1 horses. It has a subset of k horses that, by inductive supposition, are all the same color. Let x be the horse omitted from this subset. Consider a different subset of k horses that omits some horse y instead of x. Again, all horses in this subset must be the same color. Therefore x is the same color as y. So the proposition holds for n=k+1, and therefore for all n…

… Finally, I have seen a white horse, so all horses must be the same color as it, white.
